# Slide pages in ionic (images from json request)

Tags: html, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a JSON which consists of image,title and description.(json of news) I want to create view that shows the image,title and description in a page. I should be able to slide the page to view the next news item. I'm using angularjs and ionic framework to do this.

The way i tried it shows all the images in the same page

Mycode

```
<ion-view title="News" ng-controller="NewsCtrl">
    <ion-content  class="has-header" scroll="true" padding="true">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="newsS in news">
                <ion-slide>
                        <img ng-src= http://@@@@@@@@/{{newsS.image}}> 
                         <b><h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{newsS.title}}</h4></b><br>
                         <h5 class="list-group-item-text">{{newsS.description}}</h5>
                </ion-slide>
             </ion-item>
         </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

How can i do this? For Ex: my json looks like this

```
{
   News: [
   {
      id: "1",
      title: "dgdgdgdgdg",
      image: "uploads/news/******_logo.jpg",
      status: "yes"
   },
   {
      id: "3",
      title: "dgdgdgdgdgdg",
      description: "Solution by dgdgdgl",
      image: "uploads/news/2013_batman_arkham_origins-1920x1080.jpg",
      status: "yes"
   },
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ion-slide-box

```
<ion-slide-box>
  <ion-slide ng-repeat="n in news">
    <img ng-src="{{n.image}}">
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Reference:

[ion-slide-box](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/)

Comment: this works? I need to adjust the width of browser then only display the slider. @@